# How does the snowball fight animation on the Winter Bash page work?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2015

As you all can see in the [Winter Bash page](https://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/), there are people playing in the snow (first time ever I am seeing some snow in teal ;) , and I choose to believe that its snow);

[image]

How is this working? Are these some gif animations, or something else? Sometimes, the are playing and I once saw them sitting in a heart shaped formation. Is the source available online? Is there any way / workaround to build a similar one?

Comment: It's HTML5 Canvas.

Comment: The real question is how to get them to make the heart.

Comment: Is the source available or is there any way to make one of my own?

Comment: “playing in the snow” – I wonder what you need to do with snow to make it teal instead of white…

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ, I'd think user at 9k with lots of JS answer would know that source to anything JS you see on web is available.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov could you help me finding this one's source?

Answer (score 4):

The code behind the animation is in [`home.js`](https://cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/js/home.js?v=834ed99c10e3). Other code in the file seems irrelevant.

```
! function() {
    function e() {
        return Date.now() / 1e3
    }

    function t(e, t, a, n, r) {
        var i = e[a] - t[a],
            s = e[n] - t[n];
        e[a] = i * W(r) - s * Y(r) + t[a], e[n] = i * Y(r) + s * W(r) + t[n]
    }

    function a() {
        this.legs = [{
            "hip_angle": 0,
            "knee_angle": 0
        }, {
            "hip_angle": 0,
            "knee_angle": 0
        }], this.arms = [{
            "shoulder_angle": 0,
            "elbow_angle": 0
        }, {
            "shoulder_angle": 0,
            "elbow_angle": 0
        }], this.direction_angle = 0, this.lean_angle = 0, this.animators = [], this.X = this.Y = this.VX = this.VY = 0, this.Z = this.VZ = 0, this.size = 1
    }

    function n(e, t, a, n, r, i, s, o) {
        return function(l) {
            if (!(a >= l)) {
                var h = l >= n;
                h && (l = n);
                var u = (l - a) / (n - a);
                switch (s) {
                    case "smooth":
                        u = -W(Math.PI * u) / 2 + .5;
                        break;
                    case "andback":
                        u = -W(Math.PI * u * 2) / 2 + .5
                }
                var c;
                c = "function" == typeof i ? i(u, r) : r * (1 - u) + i * u, e[t] = c, h && o && o()
            }
        }
    }

    function r(e) {
        return 11 + 1.5 * Y(e / 10) + e / 25
    }

    function i(e) {
        var t = "feet.0",
            a = e.feet[0].y;
        return e.feet[1].y > a && (t = "feet.1", a = e.feet[1].y), e.hands[0].y > a && (t = "hands.0", a = e.hands[0].y), e.hands[1].y > a && (t = "hands.1", a = e.hands[1].y), e.hip.y > a && (t = "hip"), t
    }

    function s(e, t) {
        for (var a = t.split(/\./), n = 0; n < a.length; n++) e = e[a[n]];
        return e
    }

    function o(e) {
        for (var a = {
                "x": 0,
                "y": 0,
                "z": 0
            }, n = {
                "x": 0,
                "y": -.5 * e.size,
                "z": 0
            }, r = {
                "x": 0,
                "y": -.6 * e.size,
                "z": 0
            }, i = {
                "x": 0,
                "y": -.7 * e.size,
                "z": 0
            }, s = [], o = [], l = [], h = [], u = 0; 2 > u; u++) {
            var c = u ? -1 : 1;
            s[u] = {
                "x": .05 * c * e.size,
                "y": .4 * e.size,
                "z": 0
            }, o[u] = {
                "x": .1 * c * e.size,
                "y": .8 * e.size,
                "z": 0
            }, l[u] = {
                "x": .05 * c * e.size,
                "y": n.y + .3 * e.size,
                "z": 0
            }, h[u] = {
                "x": .1 * c * e.size,
                "y": n.y + .6 * e.size,
                "z": 0
            }
        }
        for (var u = 0; 2 > u; u++) t(s[u], a, "y", "z", e.legs[u].hip_angle), t(o[u], a, "y", "z", e.legs[u].hip_angle), t(o[u], s[u], "y", "z", -e.legs[u].knee_angle), t(l[u], n, "y", "z", e.arms[u].shoulder_angle), t(h[u], n, "y", "z", e.arms[u].shoulder_angle), t(h[u], l[u], "y", "z", e.arms[u].elbow_angle);
        t(n, a, "y", "z", -e.lean_angle), t(r, a, "y", "z", -e.lean_angle), t(i, a, "y", "z", -e.lean_angle);
        for (var u = 0; 2 > u; u++) t(l[u], a, "y", "z", -e.lean_angle), t(h[u], a, "y", "z", -e.lean_angle);
        for (var u = 0; 2 > u; u++) t(s[u], a, "x", "z", e.direction_angle), t(o[u], a, "x", "z", e.direction_angle), t(l[u], a, "x", "z", e.direction_angle), t(h[u], a, "x", "z", e.direction_angle);
        return t(n, a, "x", "z", e.direction_angle), t(r, a, "x", "z", e.direction_angle), t(i, a, "x", "z", e.direction_angle), {
            "hip": a,
            "shoulder": n,
            "knees": s,
            "feet": o,
            "neck": r,
            "hands": h,
            "elbows": l,
            "head": i
        }
    }

    function l(e, t, a, n, r, i, s) {
        t.save();
        var o = (1 - (200 - r) / 400) / .6;
        t.scale(i, i), t.translate(25, 0), t.scale(o, o), t.translate(-25, 0), t.translate(a, n), t.lineWidth = 1 / i, t.fillStyle = t.strokeStyle = s || "white", t.beginPath(), t.moveTo(e.neck.x, e.neck.y), t.lineTo(e.hip.x, e.hip.y), t.lineTo(e.knees[0].x, e.knees[0].y), t.lineTo(e.feet[0].x, e.feet[0].y), t.moveTo(e.hip.x, e.hip.y), t.lineTo(e.knees[1].x, e.knees[1].y), t.lineTo(e.feet[1].x, e.feet[1].y), t.moveTo(e.shoulder.x, e.shoulder.y), t.lineTo(e.elbows[0].x, e.elbows[0].y), t.lineTo(e.hands[0].x, e.hands[0].y), t.moveTo(e.shoulder.x, e.shoulder.y), t.lineTo(e.elbows[1].x, e.elbows[1].y), t.lineTo(e.hands[1].x, e.hands[1].y), t.stroke(), t.beginPath(), t.arc(e.head.x, e.head.y, .1, 0, 2 * Math.PI), t.save(), t.fill(), t.restore(), t.stroke(), t.restore()
    }

    function h(e, t) {
        return function(a, n) {
            return .5 >= a ? (a = 2 * a, a * e + (1 - a) * n) : (a = 2 * a - 1, a * t + (1 - a) * e)
        }
    }

    function u(e, t) {
        var a;
        return "number" == typeof t ? (a = (t - e.direction_angle) % Q, a > Math.PI && (a -= Q), a < -Math.PI && (a += Q), a > Math.PI || -40 * T > a ? a = -40 * T : (a < -Math.PI || a > 40 * T) && (a = 40 * T)) : a = 0, a
    }

    function c(e) {
        var t = u(this, e);
        return this.animate(.2, {
            "legs": {
                "rear_leg": {
                    "hip_angle": [10 * T, "smooth"],
                    "knee_angle": [20 * T, "smooth"]
                },
                "front_leg": {
                    "hip_angle": [0 * T, "smooth"],
                    "knee_angle": [0 * T, "smooth"]
                }
            },
            "direction_angle": "" + t
        }, "linear")
    }

    function d(e, t) {
        var a = u(this, e);
        return this.animate(t || .6, {
            "legs": {
                "rear_leg": {
                    "hip_angle": [30 * T, "smooth"],
                    "knee_angle": h(70 * T, 0 * T)
                },
                "front_leg": {
                    "hip_angle": -20 * T,
                    "knee_angle": h(10 * T, 10 * T)
                }
            },
            "arms": {
                "rear_leg": {
                    "shoulder_angle": h(0, -40 * T),
                    "elbow_angle": h(0, 20 * T)
                },
                "front_leg": {
                    "shoulder_angle": h(0, 15 * T),
                    "elbow_angle": h(0, 25 * T)
                }
            },
            "lean_angle": h(-5 * T, 2 * T),
            "direction_angle": "" + a
        }, "linear")
    }

    function p(e, t) {
        var a = u(this, e);
        return this.animate(t || .3, {
            "legs": {
                "rear_leg": {
                    "hip_angle": [60 * T, "linear"],
                    "knee_angle": h(120 * T, 0 * T)
                },
                "front_leg": {
                    "hip_angle": -40 * T,
                    "knee_angle": h(10 * T, 10 * T)
                }
            },
            "arms": {
                "rear_leg": {
                    "shoulder_angle": h(0, -80 * T),
                    "elbow_angle": h(0, 80 * T)
                },
                "front_leg": {
                    "shoulder_angle": h(0, 40 * T),
                    "elbow_angle": h(0, 60 * T)
                }
            },
            "lean_angle": h(25 * T, 15 * T),
            "direction_angle": "" + a
        }, "linear")
    }

    function g(e) {
        return this.animate(e || .6, {
            "legs": {
                "front_leg": {
                    "hip_angle": 5 * T,
                    "knee_angle": 0
                },
                "rear_leg": {
                    "hip_angle": -5 * T,
                    "knee_angle": h(45 * T, 0)
                }
            },
            "arms": [{
                "shoulder_angle": 0,
                "elbow_angle": 0
            }, {
                "shoulder_angle": 0,
                "elbow_angle": 0
            }],
            "lean_angle": 0
        })
    }

    function f(e) {
        return this.animate(e || .7, {
            "legs": [{
                "hip_angle": 80 * T,
                "knee_angle": 160 * T
            }, {
                "hip_angle": 80 * T,
                "knee_angle": 160 * T
            }],
            "arms": [{
                "shoulder_angle": 20 * T,
                "elbow_angle": 20 * T
            }, {
                "shoulder_angle": 20 * T,
                "elbow_angle": 0
            }],
            "lean_angle": 45 * T
        }, "linear")
    }

    function v() {
        return this.animate(1, {
            "legs": [{
                "hip_angle": h(120 * T, 102 * T),
                "knee_angle": 40 * T
            }, {
                "hip_angle": h(120 * T, 122 * T),
                "knee_angle": 80 * T
            }],
            "arms": [{
                "shoulder_angle": -10 * T,
                "elbow_angle": 10 * T
            }, {
                "shoulder_angle": -20 * T,
                "elbow_angle": 20 * T
            }],
            "lean_angle": -20 * T
        }, "smooth")
    }

    function y() {
        return this.animate(.7, {
            "legs": [{
                "hip_angle": h(160 * T, 100 * T),
                "knee_angle": 160 * T
            }, {
                "hip_angle": h(160 * T, 100 * T),
                "knee_angle": 160 * T
            }],
            "arms": [{
                "shoulder_angle": 20 * T,
                "elbow_angle": 20 * T
            }, {
                "shoulder_angle": 20 * T,
                "elbow_angle": 0
            }],
            "lean_angle": 45 * T
        }, "linear")
    }

    function m() {
        return this.animate(.8, {
            "legs": [{
                "hip_angle": -5 * T,
                "knee_angle": 50 * T
            }, {
                "hip_angle": -5 * T,
                "knee_angle": 50 * T
            }],
            "arms": [{
                "shoulder_angle": 95 * T,
                "elbow_angle": 0 * T
            }, {
                "shoulder_angle": 90 * T,
                "elbow_angle": 0 * T
            }],
            "lean_angle": h(90 * T, 80 * T)
        }, "linear")
    }

    function b(e) {
        switch (e) {
            case 1:
                return this.animate(.2, {
                    "arms": [{
                        "shoulder_angle": -30 * T,
                        "elbow_angle": 90 * T
                    }]
                }, "smooth");
            case 2:
                return this.animate(.6, {
                    "arms": [{
                        "shoulder_angle": 90 * T,
                        "elbow_angle": h(90 * T, 0)
                    }]
                }, "smooth");
            case 3:
                return this.animate(.4, {
                    "arms": [{
                        "shoulder_angle": 30 * T,
                        "elbow_angle": 60 * T
                    }]
                }, "smooth")
        }
    }

    function S(e, t) {
        switch (e) {
            case 1:
                return this.animate(.6, {
                    "lean_angle": -20 * T,
                    "arms": [{
                        "shoulder_angle": 200 * T,
                        "elbow_angle": 60 * T
                    }]
                });
            case 2:
                return this.animate(.4, {});
            case 3:
                var a = k(this, t.stickFigure.X, t.stickFigure.Y + t.stickFigure._last_points.neck.y, t.stickFigure.Z, t.stickFigure.VX, t.stickFigure.VZ);
                return a.thrower = this.kid, this.animate(.4, {
                    "lean_angle": 30 * T,
                    "arms": [{
                        "shoulder_angle": h(120 * T, 50 * T),
                        "elbow_angle": h(0, 30 * T)
                    }],
                    "legs": [, {
                        "hip_angle": -30 * T
                    }]
                }, "smooth")
        }
    }

    function w(e, t, a, n) {
        var r, i = a - e,
            s = n - t;
        if (0 === i) r = 0 > s ? 180 * T : 0 * T;
        else {
            var o = -s / i,
                l = Math.atan(o);
            0 > i && (l += 180 * T), r = 270 * T - l
        }
        return r
    }

    function _() {
        var e = this.stickFigure = new a;
        e.kid = this, this.initial = !0, e.size = .2 * Math.random() + .5;
        var t = 46 * Math.random() + 2,
            n = 120 * Math.random() - 60;
        e.X = t, e.Z = n, e.Y = r(e.X, e.Z) - .8 * e.size, e.direction_angle = 0, this.plan = [];
        var i = this;
        x = J + D, e.when_idle = function() {
            i.doSomething()
        }
    }

    function k(t, a, n, i, s, o) {
        for (var l = {
                "x": t._last_points.hands[0].x + t.X,
                "y": t._last_points.hands[0].y + t.Y,
                "z": t._last_points.hands[0].z + t.Z,
                "t": e()
            }, h = 7 + 6 * Math.random(), u = 0; 2 > u; u++) {
            var c = a - l.x,
                d = n - l.y,
                p = i - l.z,
                g = Math.sqrt(c * c + p * p);
            l.vx = c * h / g, l.vz = p * h / g;
            var f = g / h;
            a += s * f, i += o * f
        }
        return l.vy = Math.max(-10, -4.905 * f + d / f), K.push(l), l.step = function() {
            var t = e(),
                a = t - this.t;
            a > .04 && (a = .04), this.vy += 9.81 * a, this.y += this.vy * a, this.x += this.vx * a, this.z += this.vz * a, this.y > r(this.x, this.z) && (this.gone = !0), this.t = t
        }, l.draw = function(e, t) {
            e.save();
            var a = (1 - (200 - this.z) / 400) / .6;
            e.scale(t, t), e.translate((this.x - 25) * a + 25, this.y * a), e.scale(a, a), e.lineWidth = 1 / t, e.fillStyle = e.strokeStyle = "white", e.beginPath(), e.arc(0, 0, .04, 0, 2 * Math.PI), e.save(), e.fill(), e.restore(), e.stroke(), e.restore()
        }, l
    }
    var x, I = 0,
        z = function(e) {
            return window[e + (e ? "R" : "r") + "equestAnimationFrame"]
        },
        H = z("") || z("webkit") || z("moz") || z("o") || z("ms") || function(e) {
            var t = Date.now(),
                a = t - I;
            I = t, setTimeout(function() {
                e()
            }, 16 - a % 16)
        },
        T = Math.PI / 180,
        F = 1,
        C = 2,
        B = 3,
        E = 4,
        A = 5,
        j = 6,
        D = 7,
        M = 8,
        U = 9,
        O = 10,
        P = 11,
        L = 1,
        q = 11,
        X = 12,
        V = 13,
        Z = 21,
        N = 22,
        J = 23,
        Y = Math.sin,
        W = Math.cos;
    a.prototype.stop = function(e) {
        return this.animators = [], !e && this.when_idle && this.when_idle(), this
    }, a.prototype.animate = function(t, a, r) {
        function i(a, h) {
            for (var u in a)
                if (a.hasOwnProperty(u)) {
                    var c = u;
                    if ("front_leg" === u ? c = o : "rear_leg" === u && (c = 1 - o), "object" == typeof h[c]) i(a[u], h[c]);
                    else {
                        var d, p;
                        a[u].constructor == Array ? (d = a[u][0], p = a[u][1]) : (p = r, d = a[u]), "string" == typeof d && (d = h[c] + parseFloat(d)), s.animators.push(n(h, c, e(), e() + t, h[c], d, p, l)), l = null
                    }
                }
        }
        var s = this,
            o = this.legs[0].hip_angle >= this.legs[1].hip_angle ? 0 : 1,
            l = function() {
                s.animators = [], s.when_idle && s.when_idle()
            };
        return i(a, this), l && l(), this
    }, a.prototype.step = function() {
        for (var t = this._last_time, a = e(), n = this.animators.length, l = n - 1; l >= 0; l--) this.animators[l] && this.animators[l](a);
        var h = o(this),
            u = i(h),
            c = s(h, u),
            d = {
                "x": this.X,
                "y": r(this.X + c.x, this.Z + c.z) - c.y,
                "z": this.Z
            };
        if ("undefined" != typeof t) {
            var p = this._last_points,
                g = (this._last_hip, a - t);
            if (this.VY += 9.81 * g, this.Y += this.VY * g, c.y + this.Y >= r(this.X + c.x, this.Z + c.z)) {
                var f = c.x - s(p, u).x,
                    v = c.z - s(p, u).z;
                Math.abs(f) > .1, this.VX = -f / g, this.X -= f, this.VZ = -v / g, this.Z -= v, this.VY > 0 && (this.VY = 0), this.Y = r(this.X + c.x, this.Z + c.z) - c.y
            } else this.X += this.VX * g, this.Z += this.VZ * g
        }
        this._last_time = a, this._last_hip = d, this._last_points = h, 0 === n && this.when_idle && this.when_idle()
    };
    var Q = 2 * Math.PI;
    _.prototype.step = function() {
        this.stickFigure.step()
    }, _.prototype.doSomething = function() {
        if (!this.plan || !this.plan.length) return this.decide(), void 0;
        var e = this.plan[0][0];
        switch (e) {
            case F:
                return;
            case C:
                this.stickFigure.animate(this.plan[0][1], {
                    "_ignore": 0
                }), this.plan.shift();
                break;
            case B:
                v.call(this.stickFigure), this.plan.shift();
                break;
            case E:
                y.call(this.stickFigure), this.plan.shift();
                break;
            case A:
                f.call(this.stickFigure), this.plan.shift();
                break;
            case j:
                g.call(this.stickFigure), this.plan.shift();
                break;
            case D:
                m.call(this.stickFigure), this.plan.shift();
                break;
            case O:
                for (var t = this.plan[0][1], a = Math.abs(t - this.stickFigure.direction_angle); a >= Q;) a -= Q;
                if (2 * T > a) return this.plan.shift(), void 0;
                c.call(this.stickFigure, this.plan[0][1]);
                break;
            case M:
            case U:
                var n = this.plan[0][1],
                    r = n - this.stickFigure.X,
                    i = this.plan[0][2],
                    s = i - this.stickFigure.Z;
                if (Math.abs(r) + Math.abs(s) > 1) {
                    var o = w(this.stickFigure.X, this.stickFigure.Z, n, i);
                    return (e === U ? p : d).call(this.stickFigure, o, this.plan[0][3]), void 0
                }
                return this.plan.shift(), void 0;
            case P:
                var l = this.plan[0][1].shift();
                if (!l) return this.plan.shift(), void 0;
                switch (l) {
                    case L:
                        f.call(this.stickFigure);
                        break;
                    case q:
                    case X:
                    case V:
                        b.call(this.stickFigure, parseInt(l % 10));
                        break;
                    case j:
                        g.call(this.stickFigure);
                        break;
                    case O:
                        for (var h = this.plan[0][2], o = w(this.stickFigure.X, this.stickFigure.Y, h.stickFigure.X, h.stickFigure.Y), a = Math.abs(o - this.stickFigure.direction_angle); a >= Q;) a -= Q;
                        if (15 * T > a) return;
                        c.call(this.stickFigure, o), this.plan[0][1].unshift(O), g.call(this.stickFigure);
                        break;
                    case Z:
                    case N:
                    case J:
                        S.call(this.stickFigure, parseInt(l % 10), this.plan[0][2])
                }
        }
    };
    var R = 0;
    _.prototype.decide = function() {
        if (!this.initial && Math.random() > .4 + R / 50) {
            for (var e, t = 0; 10 > t; t++) {
                var a = G[Math.random() * G.length | 0];
                if (a !== this && Math.abs(this.stickFigure.X - a.stickFigure.X) < 10 && Math.abs(this.stickFigure.Z - a.stickFigure.Z) < 10) {
                    e = a;
                    break
                }
            }
            if (e) return this.plan.push([P, [L, q, X, V, j, O, Z, N, J], e]), void 0
        }
        this.initial = !1;
        var n = 46 * Math.random() + 2,
            r = 120 * Math.random() - 60,
            i = this.stickFigure.X - n,
            s = this.stickFigure.Z - r,
            o = Math.abs(i) + Math.abs(s) > 7 && Math.random() < .7 - R / 50;
        this.plan.push([o ? U : M, n, r, .2 * Math.random() - .1 + (o ? .3 : .6)])
    };
    var K = [],
        G = [];
    $(function() {
        function t() {
            var r = e();
            r - s >= 1 && (o = 1 - Math.round(a.position().top) / (3 * x), s = r);
            for (var c = r - .04, d = -100, p = -100, g = .1 / (G.length - 1), f = -g, v = 0; v < G.length; v++) {
                if (v || (R = R * o + o * (r - (G[v].stickFigure._last_time || r))), (R + Math.PI / 2) * x > h && !i) {
                    do {
                        f += g;
                        var y = Q * f,
                            m = 13 * W(y) - y * W(2 * y) - 2 * W(3 * y) - W(4 * y),
                            b = 4 * (3 * Y(y) - Y(3 * y))
                    } while (3.6 > (b - d) * (b - d) + (m - p) * (m - p));
                    d = b, p = m, m = -5 * m - 10, b = 25 + b * ((60 - m) / 160);
                    var S = w(b, m, 25, -10);
                    u.push([b, m, S]), v === G.length - 1 && (i = r)
                }
                G[v].stickFigure._last_time < c && (G[v].stickFigure._last_time = c), G[v].step()
            }
            n.clearRect(0, 0, n.canvas.width, n.canvas.height), n.save(), n.translate(0, -30);
            for (var v = 0; v < G.length; v++) {
                var _ = G[v].stickFigure,
                    k = _._last_points;
                l(k, n, _.X, _.Y, _.Z, 25, "#e4f4f3")
            }
            for (var v = K.length; v >= 0; v--) {
                var I = K[v];
                if (I) {
                    if (I.step(), I.gone) {
                        K.splice(v, 1);
                        continue
                    }
                    I.draw(n, 25)
                }
                if (I && I.vy > 0 || u.length)
                    for (var z = 0; z < G.length; z++) {
                        var C = G[z],
                            U = u.shift();
                        if (U) G[z].plan = [
                            [M, U[0], U[1], .5 + .1 * Math.random()],
                            [j],
                            [O, U[2]],
                            [A],
                            [B],
                            [F]
                        ];
                        else if (Math.abs(I.x - C.stickFigure.X) < .2 && Math.abs(I.z - C.stickFigure.Z) < .2 && Math.abs(I.y - (C.stickFigure.Y + C.stickFigure._last_points.hip.y)) < .3) {
                            C.stickFigure.VY = -1.8 - .4 * Math.random();
                            var $ = C.stickFigure.VX * I.vx > 0 ? -1 : 1,
                                et = 3 + 2 * Math.random();
                            C.stickFigure.VX = +I.vx / et, C.stickFigure.VZ = +I.vz / et, C.plan = [
                                [B],
                                [E],
                                [j]
                            ], C.plan = $ > 0 && Math.random() < .8 - R / 40 ? [
                                [D],
                                [P, [L, q, X, V, j, O, Z, N, J], I.thrower]
                            ] : $ > 0 ? [
                                [D],
                                [j]
                            ] : [
                                [B],
                                [E],
                                [j]
                            ], C.stickFigure.stop(!0).animate(.3, {
                                "lean_angle": 80 * $ * T,
                                "legs": [{
                                    "hip_angle": 90 * -$ * T,
                                    "knee_angle": 0
                                }, {
                                    "hip_angle": 90 * -$ * T,
                                    "knee_angle": 0
                                }]
                            }, "linear"), K.splice(v, 1);
                            break
                        }
                    }
            }
            n.restore(), H(t)
        }
        for (var a = $("canvas").fadeIn(1e3), n = a[0].getContext("2d"), r = 0; 50 > r; r++) G.push(new _);
        var i = 0,
            s = e(),
            o = 0,
            h = a.width(),
            u = [];
        H(t)
    })
}();
```

Comment: is there any way to setup fiddle?? https://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/pL301thk/

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ first problem with your fiddle is your using pure JS while there is Jquery in the code but even selecting 1.7.2 didn't seem to get it working so there may be something more like a bind or something